# How to prevent from downloading and running script?

Tags: javascript, c++, internet-explorer-8, bho

I wonder if it is possible in JavaScript to prevent `<script src="unwantedscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` object from running?

I need to make it like it never existed. Is there an event where I can prevent from executing a script (based on `src` argument)?

I'm targeting Internet Explorer 8 but solution for other browsers are also welcomed (though it won't help me in anything ;)).

And please no JQuery or other libraries. I'm writing in C++ an IE add-on but I can use interfaces from [MSHTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741322%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to 'use' JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

In IE (MSHTML) it's simple. You just 404 the HTTP request to get `unwantedscript.js`.

Comment: What? I don't understand anything from your answer ;). I don't want `unwantedscript.js`. I don't want what it does and generates. I just want to make it disappear.

Comment: You're familiar with the HTTP protocol? `404 Resource Not Found` is the response code for URL's that do not resolve. MSHTML allows you to substitute an HTTP response. So, you trick MSHTML into believing that the HTTP request for `unwantedscript.js` returns error 404. Voila, no more script.

Comment: "MSHTML allows you to substitute an HTTP response" How? Do you have any link or could provide an example code?

Comment: On rereading, `DWebBrowserEvents2::BeforeNavigate2` sounds even more promising: it has an explicit `VARIANT_BOOL *Cancel`. But the 404 trick is possible via `IDocHostUIHandler::TranslateUrl`; just point it to a URL that cannot possibly exist.

Comment: But it's not fired when downloading scripts. `BeforeNavigate2` and `TranslateUrl` are fired only before navigating to new site and for iframes (I guess, that's what I noticed from a debugger).

Answer (score 0):

Trying to block a free hosting websites ads? If you do that your site can be deleted by the hosting company so watch out.

There is really nothing you can do about it other than wrap it in conditional comments

```
<!--[if IE 5]>
    <script src="foo.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

but if it is being injected into the page, you probably can not wrap it.

Comment: He's writing a plug-in/add-on, so even if it's injected, it should be possible to block it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you (apparently) cannot inject a 404 error code for scripts, here's another idea: Use a [custom security provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537182.aspx) and reject the .js URL.